# Can someone explain why this is the Kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[This is how my professor solved it, but I just can't get how. Please help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9XM5.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $D$ is defined as the set of all vectors $f$ such that $D(f)=0$. Let $f = a+bx+cx^2$, and suppose $f$ is in the kernel of $D$. Then by the definition of $D$,
$$0 = D(f) = b+2cx$$
In order for the right hand side to be zero, both $b$ and $c$  must be zero. If either are nonzero, then you can find a value of $x$ that makes the RHS nonzero. Thus, only $a$ can be nonzero, so any polynomial of the form $a=a+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2$ is in the kernel of $D$. The kernel is one-dimensional, so any nonzero vector gives us a basis.

Comment: So if it had been 3-dimensional would the answer have been {3}?

Comment: No, the span of $\{3\}$ consists of every multiple of $3$, i.e. every constant polynomial. If the kernel were three dimensional, then you would need three vectors to form a basis. In this case, the kernel would just be the whole vector space, so $\{1,x,x^2\}$ would be a good basis.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, if   f=3a+bx+cx^2 then span would be {3}?

Comment: The span of what? Further, the span of any set is a vector space, and the set $\{3\}$ is not a vector space.

Comment: So in what instance would the answer of a question like this just be {3}, that is what I was trying to ask.

Comment: If you're looking for the basis of the kernel of $D$, then $\{3\}$ is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the derivative mapping on polynomials of degree at most two. We must ask ourselves which functions have derivative zero in this set. The answer? All constant polynomials.

The kernel of a linear mapping is the collection of those vectors that get mapped to zero. The constants do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at derivatives of quadratics. To compute the kernel of the map, he/she just looks at $D(p(x)) = 0 = 0+ 0x + 0x^2$. You know what $D(p(x))$ for arbitrary $p(x)$, namely $b+2cx$. In the last step, we just equate coefficients to solve for the variables on the LHS of the equation. And since this equation is independent of $a$ which is the constant term in the polynomial (due to the fact that $a$ disappears in the derivative), we have that kernel is just the constant polynomials.